# create list from list where values only increase by 1

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have the code below that gets the maximum value from a list.  It then compares it to the maximum value of the remaining values in the list, and if it is more than 1 higher than the next greatest value, it replaces the original list maximum with 1 higher than the next greatest value.  I would like the code to search the entire list and make sure that any value in the list is at most 1 larger than any other value in the list.  I know this ins’t the best worded explanation, I hope the example lists below make what I’m trying to accomplish clearer.

for example I don’t want to get a final list like:

```
[0,2,0,3]
```

I would want the final list to be

```
[0,1,0,2]
```

input:

```
empt=[0,2,0,0]
```

Code:

```
nwEmpt=[i for i in empt if i !=max(empt)]


nwEmpt2=[]

for i in range(0,len(empt)):
    if (empt[i]==max(empt))&(max(empt)>(max(nwEmpt)+1)):
        nwEmpt2.append((max(nwEmpt)+1))
    elif (empt[i]==max(empt))&(max(empt)==(max(nwEmpt)+1)):
        nwEmpt2.append(max(empt))
    else:
        nwEmpt2.append(empt[i])
```

output:

```
nwEmpt2

[0,1,0,0]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related to your issue, but the `&` is the bitwise-and operator. If you want to do logical-and (which it looks like), you want the `and` operator instead. That would let you get rid of most of your grouping parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
min_value = min(empt)
empt_set = set(empt)
for i in empt:
  nwEmpt.append(min_value + len(list(filter(lambda x: x < i, empt_set))))
```

This gives e.g. for input `empt = [8, 10, 6, 4, 4]` output `nwEmpt = [6, 7, 5, 4, 4]`.

It works by mapping each element to (the minimum value) + (the number of distinct values smaller than element).